# Translating yaw degrees into 2D movement

Tags: movement, trigonometry

I've been hitting my head on the wall for a while with this, and I'm almost sure I'm overcomplicating it.

I have a variable for yaw in degrees (and also pitch and roll, but those should be irrelevant). I want to turn that variable into normalized 2D movement, so the distance traveled per frame should always be a constant.

I was easily able to to workout movement when I had a fixed view direction, but translating it with yaw is what's confusing me. I've been trying a combination of converting to radians, then using cos(x) and sin(x) but it only works if I'm looking in a certain direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, was definitely overthinking it. Here's the quick version, probably some ways to optimize it:

```
        double x = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw));
        double z = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw));
        double xo = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw + 90)); // 90 offset of current direction
        double zo = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw + 90));

        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
            position.z -= MOVESPEED * z;
            position.x += MOVESPEED * x;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
            position.z -= MOVESPEED * zo;
            position.x += MOVESPEED * xo;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
            position.z += MOVESPEED * zo;
            position.x -= MOVESPEED * xo;
        }
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
            position.z += MOVESPEED * z;
            position.x -= MOVESPEED * x;
        }
```